# entity framework many-to-many add/delete object issues

Tags: entity-framework, entity

For instance I have persons, locations and a personlocation table to link the two. I also have a role and personrole table.

```
 Tables:

Person (personid, name)

Personlocation (personid, locationid)

Location (locationid, description)

Personrole (personid, roleid)

Role (roleid, description)
```

EF will give me persons, roles and location entities.

Since EF will NOT generate the personlocation and personrole entity types, they cannot be 
used in the query.

QUESTION: how can i add a Person object and return personid and then add that id with 3 roleids into Personrole table/association?

e.g.

```
Person p = new Person();
p.name = "John"
......
entity.AddToPersons(p);
for(var roleid in Roleid)
entity.AddtoRoles(roleid)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't *need* to map the join tables when there is nothing but the FK's - that is a good thing. It is smart enough to do a "silent-join" behind the scenes.

> QUESTION: how can i add a Person object and return personid and then add that id with 3 roleids into Personrole table/association?

You just need to use the "Roles" association on the "Person" entity. You don't need to add straight to the "Role" table.

E.g:

```
// Create new Person
Person p = new Person();
p.Name = "John";

// Create new Role
Role r = new Role();
r.Description = "Administrator";

// Add new Role to this new Person
p.Roles.Add(r);

// Add Person to context (no need to add Role)
ctx.AddToPersons(p);

// Save Changes
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Entity Framework is pretty smart. It will see there is a new role, add that first, then add a person, then add the record in the join table based on the id for the role that was just created.

HTH.

**EDIT - In response to comment:**

> *thx, what if i want to add existing role ( e.g. Roleid = 1, description="Editor")*

Very similar to above.

Just fetch the existing role from the DB, and add it to the person:

```
Role r = ctx.Roles.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RoleId == 1 && x.Description == "Editor");
p.Roles.Add(r);
```

Comment: thx, what if i want to add existing role ( e.g. Roleid = 1, description="Editor")

Comment: thx, if i wanna add a collection of roleids, i got errors by doing that: Role r = ctx.Roles.Where(x => x.RoleId == 1 && x.x.RoleId == 2);
p.Roles.Add(r);

Comment: so which leaves me with no option other than adding them one by one

Comment: How can a RoleId have Id == 1 && Id == 2?  What's the PK on the Role's table? But yes - you have to add one by one.